# If $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, prove that $gH=Hg$ for $g\in G$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> If $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, prove that $gH=Hg$ for $g\in G$.

I am not sure where to begin with this proof. I would assume we use set equality to prove it, but I don't know where to begin with that either...

Do I say that since $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, then $gHg^{-1}=H$?

Comment: Begin with an element of the form $gh$ ($h \in H$) and then show it must be of the form $h'g$ ($h' \in H$).

Comment: You can, but that's not exactly helpful. Take some element of $gH$, say $gh$ and show it is in $Hg$. How might you do this? After that, take some element of $Hg$ and show it is in $gH$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \in gH$, then $x=gh$ for some $g \in G$ and some $h \in H$. Then we get

$xg^{-1}=ghg^{-1} \in H$, hence $x=xg^{-1}g \in Hg$.

We have shown: $gH \subseteq Hg$.

It is now your turn to show: $gH \supseteq Hg$.

Comment: This is what I got: Let $x\in Hg$. Then $x =hg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ since $G$ is a group. Then $gx=ghg^{-1}\in H$. Then $g^{-1}gx\in gH$. Then $Hg\subset gH$. What do you think?